# JSLint error: "unnecessary else after disruption"

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, jslint

I am wondering how I can re-write this function to resolve the JSLint error "unnecessary else after disruption". I understand the basics of this error, and have already rewritten functions of a model like

```
 myFunction.doThing = function () {
   if (user.likesCats) {
     return patCat;
   }
   else (user.likesDogs {
     return patDog;
   }
 };
```

to be like this instead:

```
 myFunction.doThing = function () {
   if (user.likesCats) {
     return patCat;
   }
   return patDog;
 };
```

But I am unsure how to fix the if, else if, else construction in this function so that it conforms to JSLint's "do not continue with unnecessary else's after a break" rule:

```
myFunction.getRange = function () {
  if (this.settings.allowedValues) {
    return {
      min: Min,
      max: Max
    };
  } else if (this.settings.range) {
    return {
      min: range[0],
      max: range[1]
    };
  } else {
    return {
      min: 0,
      max: 1
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two approaches to this: [Single Exit Point](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingleFunctionExitPoint) vs. [Early Exit](http://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#use-early-exits-and-continue-to-simplify-code). I personally prefer the latter:

```
myFunction.getRange = function () {

  if (this.settings.allowedValues) {
    return {
      min: Min,
      max: Max
    };
  } 

  if (this.settings.range) {
    return {
      min: range[0],
      max: range[1]
    };
  }

  return {
    min: 0,
    max: 1
  };

};
```

In this case it doesn't matter much, but real-life code with early exits (`return`, `break` etc) is easier to read and maintain than "single exit" one with many `else` branches and temp variables.

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't you just set a variable instead of returning it

```
myFunction.getRange = function () {
    var range;
    if (this.settings.allowedValues) {
        range = {
            "min": Min,
            "max": Max
        };
    } else if (this.settings.range) {
        range = {
            "min": range[0],
            "max": range[1]
        };
    } else {
        range = {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 1
        };
    }
    return range;
};
```

Comment: Much easier to read, there really is no reason to have more than one return in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the final else - it's not needed. If the previous conditions aren't met it will just return those values anyway.

```
myFunction.getRange = function () {
  if (this.settings.allowedValues) {
    return {
      min: Min,
      max: Max
    };
  } else if (this.settings.range) {
    return {
      min: range[0],
      max: range[1]
    };
  }
  return { min: 0, max: 1 };
};
```